# Queued animations in javascript (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

I have a couple of SVG Lines that connect to dots. I want to animate these lines one by one to give the impression they're being drawn.

My code is set up like this:

```
function connectDots(dots){
  var lines = document.querySelectorAll(".connection-line")
  var wait = 300 //Execute 1 animation every 300 ms
  for(i=1; i<dots.length; i++){
    // Some irrelevant logic
    drawLine(line,wait*(i-1));
  }
}

function drawLine(line, offset){
  var interval = 5;
  var animation = setInterval(draw,interval)
  function draw(){
    setTimeout(function(){
            // Animation logic
      }, offset)
    }
}
```

The `connectDots` loop iterates through the dots and draws the corresponding lines between those dots.
The animation logic is there but I'm excluding it because it's not relevant here. I think the problem is with the for-loop, which doesn't work probably because it's executed synchronously in some way and adding a controlled delay (300 * the position of the animation, like 0 for the first, 300 for the second, 600 for the third, and so forth) for every one of those animations is not reliable.

My question: How can I properly create a queue of these lines and animate them one by one? I think I'm looking for either Deferred objects or callbacks, but I'm not sure how to start.

Additional info: The size of the array of dots (and lines) is static, not dynamic. Perhaps that simplifies the issue in this scenario.

Comment: Do you want to start them off at regular intervals, or start the next one when the previous one finishes? Your code suggests the former, but your description suggests the latter.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I am referring to the latter. This illustrates that the code is the issue I guess :)

Comment: You are using your own animation logic. So surely you must know when you reach the end of your animation?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I do, but I don't know how to properly set up an 'asynchronous queue' . I don't like the `setTimeout`.

Comment: `setTimeout()` is a perfectly acceptable way of doing it.  Another way would be to use [`window.requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), which is perhaps the more preferred way of doing it for amnimation related functions.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Thanks. However, my issue with `setTimeout` is that it's just a way to initialise some animations synchronously but add some delay to them to make it seem like they're 'queued', when in reality they're not. I would like to have one animation which is executed and, upon completion, starts the next one, no matter how long they are. I'm assuming `requestAnimationFrame()` is the way to go here?

Comment: Yes I would say so.